# Многопоточная загрузка картинок

Tags: python, python-3.x, grequests

Есть shelve словарь. Его ключи - строки, а значения ключей - списки с URL картинок из ВК (читай, как прямой url до картинок). Примерно 37K ключей, у каждого из которых до 100 значений. Сейчас использую такой код:

```
import grequests as greq
import shelve
from time import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def worker(pubs):
    count_pubs = len(pubs)
    current_count = 0
    # Перебор элементов вида (строка, [url1, url2, ...])
    for pub in pubs:
        t_start = time()  # время для статистики
        data = [greq.get(p) for p in pub[1]]
        n = 0
        for img in greq.imap(data, size=128):
            if img.status_code != 200:
                print('error', img.status_code)
                continue

            with open('imgs/{}_{}.jpg'.format(pub[0], n), 'wb') as img_file:
                img_file.write(img.content)
            n += 1
        current_count += 1
        print('[', time()-t_start, ']', current_count/count_pubs*100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 8+1
    pubs = []

    # генерация списка с url'ами, [строка, [url1, url2, ...]]
    with shelve.open('urls') as urls:
        keys = list(urls.keys())
        to_one = len(keys) // (n-1)

        for i in range(0, len(keys), to_one):
            for k in keys[i:i+to_one]:
                pubs.append((k, urls[k]))

    # Запуск процессов
    for i in range(n):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(pubs, ))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

    # Заглушка, чтобы скрипт не закрылся
    while True:
        input()
```

Судя по выводу скрипта, в среднем набор url'ов обрабатывается за 60 секунд. Это значит, что придётся ждать около 70 часов, а это очень долго. Как мне ускорить этот процесс? Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с задачей массовой загрузки файлов и сможет подсказать то, как сделать ее эффективнее

**UPD1**: во время работы этого скрипта (когда начнут работать сами worker'ы) загрузка CPU около 15%, памяти около 60%, диска 2-4%, сети 0-1%. Железо: CPU Intel Xeon e5-2680, 8 ядер, 16 потоков, ОЗУ 16 Гб, диск HDD, не ssd (но упирается не в него)

Comment: Вопрос, конечно, древний и, наверное, не актуальный, но у меня впечатление, что все процессы получают один и тот же список и качают одни и те же картинки. Надо же делить ссылки между процессами как-то )